# Contents stretching to fill HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, webview, horizontalscrollview

I'm doing an inadvisable thing here, and I know it, but I have a webview nested in a horizontalscrollview. (I needed more scrolling control than webview provides.)

The layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webRel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titlebar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <WebView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webZ"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And the results are as follows: 
[image: My webview.]

The webview isn't filling up the horizontalscrollview. The horizontalscrollview is filing the view, so I guess I could say the webview isn't filling the view even though I have both set to fill_parent. I would really, really like it if someone would help me figure out how to have the webview fill up the horizontalscrollview widthwise... because then I measure the height and use that measurement to paginate the text (which is then displayed in chunks widthwise which is why I chose horizontalscrollview.)

:D

(Alternatively, suggestions for a cleaner way to have smooth horizontal scrolling in a webview would also be helpful.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: use android:fillViewPort. It'll have the contents of the scrollview stretch to fill the view.

Comment: I encountered this problem before, but today I forgot how I solved it. Now you save me, I bet you are doctor ^_^

Answer (score 1):

WebView already supports horizontal scrolling, you should not put it inside a HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: It supports horizontal scrolling, but the only method for triggering it is scrollTo, which is really sudden and doesn't work for what I want to do.   

HorizontalScrollView has smoothScrollTo(), which I want to use. Hence the unorthodox nesting.

Comment: But that will work only if you set WebView's width to wrap_content. And even then, you might run into issues with the scroll view and the web view fighting for events.

Comment: In the final product I have it working the way I want it to, and it's responsive and scrolls beautifully ... just my calculations are off due to the unpredictable height and so I often have a lot of extra empty pages after the actual content.   (I know it's a hack, but except for the extra pages it works ... and is the best I can come up with.)